# Getting info about Windows executables on a Linux system

Tags: linux, windows

I have a bunch of Windows executables with garbled names on a Linux system. What is the most convenient method to examine these files and get some idea about what they are?

Currently the only thing I have is the filenames. I think at least we should be able to extract some program metadata, headers, string, etc. An EXE analyzer will be helpful.

Solutions such as copying them to a Windows system are not acceptable. Ideally there are methods which don't require installing another system, even on a virtual machine, or wine.

Comment: Well, I don't know of any special tools for it, though they may exist.  I'd probably start by just running `strings` on them and seeing if I found anything interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [`ExifTool`](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), which despite its name, handles more than just image files.

It's packaged as `libimage-exiftool-perl` on Debian/Ubuntu and `perl-Image-ExifTool` on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora.

Example output:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.10
File Name                       : explorer.exe
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 4.5 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2016:12:21 17:37:33-08:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2016:12:21 17:37:33-08:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2016:12:21 17:37:52-08:00
File Permissions                : rwx------
File Type                       : Win64 EXE
File Type Extension             : exe
MIME Type                       : application/octet-stream
Machine Type                    : AMD AMD64
Time Stamp                      : 2016:11:11 01:08:32-08:00
PE Type                         : PE32+
Linker Version                  : 14.0
Code Size                       : 1736704
Initialized Data Size           : 2902528
Uninitialized Data Size         : 512
Entry Point                     : 0x9edc0
OS Version                      : 10.0
Image Version                   : 10.0
Subsystem Version               : 10.0
Subsystem                       : Windows GUI
File Version Number             : 10.0.14393.479
Product Version Number          : 10.0.14393.479
File Flags Mask                 : 0x003f
File Flags                      : (none)
File OS                         : Windows NT 32-bit
Object File Type                : Executable application
File Subtype                    : 0
Language Code                   : English (U.S.)
Character Set                   : Unicode
Company Name                    : Microsoft Corporation
File Description                : Windows Explorer
File Version                    : 10.0.14393.479 (rs1_release.161110-2025)
Internal Name                   : explorer
Legal Copyright                 : © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Original File Name              : EXPLORER.EXE
Product Name                    : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Product Version                 : 10.0.14393.479
Warning                         : Possibly corrupt Version resource
```

Comment: The name is misleading, but the information is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

1) Depending on how the names are garbled, it might be possible to un-garble them, but you should give some examples how they look like.

2) `objdump -x` etc. can dump the [PE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) headers, imports, exports.

3) `strings` can look for (8-bit) ASCII strings in all kinds of files.

4) `hexdump -C` will show you a hexdump together with the ASCII interpretation.

5) `file` will tell you the file type, including many windows types, if it's not an executable.

6) `biev` can also analyze Windows EXE formats.